# Generating site with Wyam from application code

Tags: c#, wyam

Recently I started to play a little bit with static content generators and discovered Wyam. I want to run my blog based on it, but I would also like to create web interface for myself, so I can blog with any browser.

There are multiple solutions to this problem, but I got interested in possibility to start Wyam generator inside .NET application. Is it even possible or do I have to run *wyam.exe* from inside my application?

Basically what I would like to be able to do is something like this:

```
WyamGenerator generator = new WyamGenerator("path/to/wyam/folder/structure");
generator.Generate();
```

I saw in source code `Engine` class and its `Execute` method, but I'm still unsure how to wire all those things together to be able to generate my website properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out, that concepts that Wyam is based on are a little more complicated than just executing its engine and generating content. Starting point for this topic would be [Wyam embedding page](https://wyam.io/docs/usage/embedding)

Using Wyam engine is a long blog post material, so I will answer my own question only with minimal code possible to provide starting point for further investigation to whomever will find this question in future.

First we need to create `Engine` instance.

```
Engine engine = new Engine();
```

If our `input` folder is somewhere else than our current directory, we have to provide proper `RootPath` using `FileSystem` property.

```
DirectoryPath rootPath = new DirectoryPath(@"path/to/wyam/folder/structure");
engine.FileSystem.RootPath = rootPath;
```

Here is where concept of [recipes](https://wyam.io/docs/concepts/recipes) kicks in. What is recipe?

> A recipe is a pre-configured series of modules and pipelines. Each recipe can be thought of as it's own special purpose static site generator.

[Pipeline](https://wyam.io/docs/concepts/pipelines)?

> A pipeline is a series of modules executed in sequence that results in final output documents.

Having this knowledge we know, that in order to generate any content with our `Engine` we have to provide him pipelines, that we would like it to execute. Simplest way to do it is to use one of already existing recipe. In my case I wanted to programmatically create a blog

```
Blog blog = new Blog();
blog.Apply(engine);
```

This code applies pipelines configured for Blog recipe. In `Recipe` base class (which every recipe inherits from) there is `Apply` method which looks something like this (I omitted actual code for this answer to be shorter and more readable)

```
IEnumerable<Pipeline> pipelines = // here pipelines are gathered
foreach (Pipeline pipeline in pipelines)
{
    engine.Pipelines.Add(pipeline);
}
```

So if you don't want to use any predefined recipes you can just add desired pipelines to the engine directly. When pipelines are applied, we can finally generate something

```
engine.Execute();
```